# modify specific column with sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
qw12er,foo,0 bn5mgh
rt8yp,foo,10 gh78jk
bn852mv,foo,852 78ghjkh
tgbr,foo,10 ujmyhn
wsx2d,foo,0000 ui52ohn
tgbr,foo,7418529 ujmyhn
ikl896o,foo,22 wsxdc52
```

I want to modify the 3rd column and remove all numbers and space from the beginning of the 3rd column.

Then output would be as follows:

```
qw12er,foo,bn5mgh
rt8yp,foo,gh78jk
bn852mv,foo,78ghjkh
tgbr,foo,ujmyhn
wsx2d,foo,ui52ohn
tgbr,foo,ujmyhn
ikl896o,foo,wsxdc52
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution with `awk` using [`sub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
awk -F, 'sub("^[0-9]+\\s","",$3)' OFS=, file
```

Output:

```
qw12er,foo,bn5mgh
rt8yp,foo,gh78jk
bn852mv,foo,78ghjkh
tgbr,foo,ujmyhn
wsx2d,foo,ui52ohn
tgbr,foo,ujmyhn
ikl896o,foo,wsxdc52
```

Explanation:

- `-F,`: set the comma as input field separator
- `OFS=,`: set the comma as output filed separator (a space by default)
- `sub("^[0-9]+\\s","",$3)`: erase numbers followed by a space at the beginning of the string `$3` and print the current line (because "print" is the default action in `awk`)

In this way you can edit the desired column and print all the others (that in general may be many).

Answer (score 3):

I used `awk`:

```
awk -F"[ ,]" '{print $1","$2","$4 }' yourfile
```

The result:

```
qw12er,foo,bn5mgh
rt8yp,foo,gh78jk
bn852mv,foo,78ghjkh
tgbr,foo,ujmyhn
wsx2d,foo,ui52ohn
tgbr,foo,ujmyhn
ikl896o,foo,wsxdc52
```

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`:

```
awk '{FS="[, ]"; OFS=","; print $1, $2, $4}' filename
```

In `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(.*,\)[0-9]* \([^,]*\)$/\1\2/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

According to data shown it can be the following **sed**

```
sed -r 's/,[0-9 ]+ /,/' file.csv
```

In case of data variation regex should be change for more strong