# Need to remove a specific column in a CSV

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

Example input:

```
A0021,,Outside state ambulance serv,I,,0,0,,
A4217,,"Sterile water/saline, 500 ml",X,,
A4672,,"Drainage ext line, dialysis",X,,
```

Example output after first sed command

sed -i 's/("[^,]*)[,]([^"]*")/\1\2/g' file.csv :

```
A0021,,Outside state ambulance serv,I,,0,0,,
A4217,,"Sterile water/saline, 500 ml",X,,
A4672,,"Drainage ext line dialysis",X,,
```

Desired output after the last command:

```
A0021,,,I,,0,0,,
A4217,,,X,,
A4672,,,X,,
```

The third column has been giving me issues in a project and the easiest solution is to simply delete it, as it is not necessary. The commas should remain, it should just have empty contents.

I was thinking that I would need to develop a `sed` command to remove the commas contained within quotes before the command to delete the third column, as I would imagine that the easiest way to do this would be to count the commas and then delete everything between the 2nd and 3rd comma.

this is the sed command I am using the delete the commas inside of the quotes before I proceed with clearing the 3rd column's contents

Comment: Try to read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335905/modify-specific-column-with-sed-or-awk/336065#336065). In your case I would use: `awk -F, 'sub($3,"")' OFS=, file.csv`

Comment: But I suggest you to post also your expected output and the command(s) you've tried so far.

Comment: @andreatsh that wouldn't work since the third field contains quoted commas and awk won't see that.  If that's the only field with quotes, you might try `awk -F'"' '{$2=""}'` which will delete everything between the quotes, whether there are commas or not.

Comment: @andreatsh I have went ahead and added the sed command I will be using to clear the comma contained quotes. I will test the awk provided to see if that does what I expect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );

open( my $input, '<', 'test3.csv' ) or die $!;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($input) ) {
   $row->[2] = "";
   $csv -> print( \*STDOUT, $row );
}
```

(You probably want to open an output file and `print` to that instead though).